# GoLang Socket.io Emit not Being Recieved by React

Tags: reactjs, sockets, go

I am new to golang and I didnt find other variations of example of emit and broadcast of the latest version of: https://github.com/googollee/go-socket.io/ which is one of the socketio libraries of golang.

First here is my code for golang taken from example:

```
func InitSessionServer() {



    server := socketio.NewServer(&engineio.Options{
        Transports: []transport.Transport{
            &polling.Transport{
                CheckOrigin: allowOriginFunc,
            },
            &websocket.Transport{
                CheckOrigin: allowOriginFunc,
            },
        },
    })

    server.OnConnect("/", func(s socketio.Conn) error {
        s.SetContext("")
        log.Println("connected:", s.ID())
        return nil
    })

   server.OnEvent("/", "status", func(s socketio.Conn, msg string) {
    log.Println("Message ", msg)
    s.Emit("reply", msg)
    })



    server.OnError("/", func(s socketio.Conn, e error) {
        log.Println("meet error:", e)
    })

    server.OnDisconnect("/", func(s socketio.Conn, reason string) {
        log.Println("closed", reason)
    })

    go func() {
        if err := server.Serve(); err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("socketio listen error: %s\n", err)
        }
    }()
    defer server.Close()

    http.Handle("/socket.io/", server)

    log.Println("Serving at localhost:8000...")
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil))

}
```

So its very basic. We make the `status` event our main focus in this experiment. In my assumption, since this is a socket server. Whenever I pass something to the `status` event, for example in `iocat` which is a tool where you can test your socket on a linux terminal

```
 npx iocat --socketio ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ -e status

 > test
```

This means that test gets recieved by `status` event and emits it to `reply` then I will have my react app recieve reply from the port and dispaly the contents of the message. Thus my react socket implementation below:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import io from 'socket.io-client'
const BROADCAST_SERVER_URL = 'http://192.168.1.12:8000/'
export const event_server = io(BROADCAST_SERVER_URL, {
  transports: ['websocket'],
})
event_server.on('reply', function(msg){
  console.log('Status changed', msg)
});

event_server.on('connect', () => {
  console.log('connected')
})
event_server.on('disconnect', () => {
  console.log('broadcast server disconnected')
})
event_server.on('connect_error', response => {
  console.log(response)
})

function Socket({ children }) {
  return children
}
export default Socket
```

Im really lost right now on why `reply` is not receiving anything. Any idea why its not working? By the way, I logged at `connect` on react and im getting `connected` log. Im having a headache on why I cant get the emitted reply.

ADDTL: As you can observe above I have a `printLn` and that indeed shows the test message. Except that as it is being emitted I cant see it on React

Answer (score 0):

In that github package io is var not const.

```
var socket = io();
socket.on('reply', function(msg){
    $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
  });
```

I think you can try converting it to var.